# $ is not defined in fetching api in Javascript

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the data by fetching the api but when i type into the searchbox and hit enter i get the error "*Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at main.js 1*' so the data doesn't show up in the console. Can anybody help me to fix this? Thank you so much!

This is my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Music Player</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/48a972c999.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styless.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="form" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="search" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my main.js:

```
$(
    "#form"
).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var query = $('#search').val()

    var API_KEY = '68e5388d12762a96f2d8a75bd05d285d'

    var url = `http://api.serpstack.com/search
    ?access_key=${API_KEY}

    &type=web

    &query=${query}`

    $.get(url, function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    })

})
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have jquery imported. `$` is a thing from jquery

Comment: You've attempted to import the jQuery `.js` file as a stylesheet. Don't do that

Answer (score 1):

You should import `jQuery` using `script` tag. `<link rel="stylesheet"` is for css style files.

So your import statement should be

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```